# Filter line from Ansible stdout_lines result

Tags: linux, filter, grep, ansible, stdout

I am trying to filter out a line out of Ansible stdout_lines result. The ansible playbook task I ran was the following shell argument:

```
- name: VERIFY | Confirm that queue exists properly
  shell: aws sqs list-queues --region {{region}}
  environment: "{{ aws_cli_environment|d({}) }}"
  register: sqs_list
```

To see the results, I followed it up with a debug:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ sqs_list.stdout_lines|list }}"
```

which gives the following result during the playbook run:

```
TASK [sqs : debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "{",
        "    \"QueueUrls\": [",
        "        \"sampleurl1\",",
        "        \"sampleurl2\",",
        "        \"sampleurl3\",",
        "        \"sampleurl4\",",
        "        \"https://sampleurl5/test_sqs\"",
        "    ]",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

**I want ONLY the last url, "test_sqs" to  appear under "msg":**, I tried the following filter but had no luck:

```
- name: VERIFY | Find SQS url
  command: "{{ sqs_list.stdout_lines|list }} -- formats | grep $sqs"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Script:**

```
---
- name: A simple template
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: list queue
      shell: aws sqs list-queues --region us-east-1 --queue-name-prefix test_sqs --query 'QueueUrls[*]' --output text
      register: sqs_list
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ sqs_list.stdout_lines|list }}"
```

***`Output:`***

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "https://queue.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxx/test_sqs-198O8HG46WK1Z"
    ]
}
```

You can make use of the `--queue-name-prefix` parameter to list only queues which is starting with name `test_sqs`. If there is only one queue with that name, you can use this solution.

Answer (score 6):

`aws` cli generates JSON output by default, use this advantage:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - shell: aws sqs list-queues --region eu-west-1
      register: sqs_list
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (sqs_list.stdout | from_json).QueueUrls | last }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] **********************************
TASK [command] ************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "https://eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com/xxxxx/test"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting an error trying to modify this example due to the comma character at the beginning of the json.

`- debug:
       msg: "{{ (sqs_list.stdout_lines|from_json).'{'.QueueUrls|last }}"`
or
`- debug:
       msg: "{{ (sqs_list.stdout_lines|from_json).','.QueueUrls|last }}"`

**`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ (sqs_list.stdout_lines|from_json).'{'.QueueUrls|last }}"}`**

Comment: I've provided complete *working* example. Please check your tooling. JSON output from `aws` should be valid.